# Elementor Blog Section Displays Incorrectly for Non-Logged In Users

Tags: css, wordpress, responsive-design, elementor, litespeed

I'm experiencing an issue with my website, TurnerNet.Tech, specifically with the blog section on the homepage. I recently built a new page using Elementor, and I'm encountering a problem with the display of the blog post's featured images.

The blog section is designed to display 12 posts in a 3-column layout. Each post has a featured image with a custom size. When I'm logged in, the images display correctly. However, when I view the website without being logged in, the images appear significantly larger, to the point where the image content is indiscernible.

Here is an example of an element from the Chrome Console:

```
html
Copy code
<div class="premium-blog-post-container premium-blog-skin-modern">
    <!-- ... -->
    <img decoding="async" src="https://turnernet.tech/wp-content/uploads/2023/06/Great-Reset-Promo_New.webp" title="Great-Reset-Promo_New" alt="#image_title" loading="lazy">
    <!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I've tried to resolve the issue by disabling the Asset CleanUp add-on, but the problem persists. I have the LiteSpeed Cache add-on installed and configured with both CloudFlare and Quic.Cloud. I have tried with Guest Optimization on and off with the same results. I don't see the issues when I am logged in.

I was expecting that disabling the Asset CleanUp add-on or adjusting the settings of the LiteSpeed Cache add-on would resolve the issue, but it did not.